# android message is not posting on twitter

Tags: android, twitter

I am trying to post my message on twitter. When I click on button, it shows me message that your data has been posted on twitter,but when I check I don't get any message. Here is my code.

```
  btnUpdateStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Call update status function
            // Get the status from EditText
            String status = txtUpdate.getText().toString();


            new updateTwitterStatus().execute(status);

        } 

    });
```

here is update twitterstatus class

```
  private class updateTwitterStatus extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Updating to twitter...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... screen_name) 
    {

        String status = null;
        try {
            ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
            builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);

            // Access Token 
            String access_token = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
            // Access Token Secret
            String access_token_secret = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, "");

            AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(access_token, access_token_secret);
            Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);

            // Update status
            twitter4j.Status response = twitter.updateStatus(status);
            Log.i(""+response, "value");
            Log.d("Status", "> " + response.getText());
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // Error in updating status
            Log.d("Twitter Update Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
    /// }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
    {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Status tweeted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                // Clearing EditText field
                txtUpdate.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

}
```

please help me. I am finding for this since a couple of days, I know I have asked this but I am not getting any appropriate solution, thankyou.

Comment: i am suffering same but i found a very strange solution. When i put the `CallbackURL` under `Application Details` in `Twitter` empty then i can't post tweet but when i filled this `CallbackURL` with any http: `url` then it's worked. so u may try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For twitter there are two libraries.

1. Twitter4j.jar (For text wall post)
2. Twitpick.jar  (for picture post)

Either you can go for [SocialAuth library](https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/downloads/list) (Well managed and simple to use)

Comment: sir i have used  Twitter4j.jar this libraray ..,but my message is not posting

Comment: try out socialAuth library

Comment: sir i am getting twitter execption..,unable to resolve host api.twitter.com no address associated with hostname

Comment: If you are using new API of twitter then url will be https://api.twitter.com something like that

Comment: @PiyushGupta yes sir i am using new api..,you are right..,but how i resolve that erro